# Remove spaces from string before period and comma

Tags: c++, regex, string

I could have a string like:

> During this time , Bond meets a stunning IRS agent , whom he seduces .

I need to remove the extra spaces before the comma and before the period in my whole string. I tried throwing this into a char vector and only not `push_back` if the current char was " " and the following char was a "." or "," but it did not work. I know there is a simple way to do it maybe using `trim(), find()`, or `erase()` or some kind of `regex` but I am not the most familiar with regex.

Comment: It think either a `regex_replace` or a `find` and `erase` on the string in a loop is going to be what you need.

Comment: Be careful with quotation marks. The current char cannot be `" "`, because that's a string literal. It can be` ' `', because that's a character constant.

Comment: @PeteBecker yes, thank you for pointing that out. I was just trying to make the question easier to read. But you are correct chars constants are in the `' '` form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be (using regex library):

```
std::string fix_string(const std::string& str) {
  static const std::regex rgx_pattern("\\s+(?=[\\.,])");
  std::string rtn;
  rtn.reserve(str.size());
  std::regex_replace(std::back_insert_iterator<std::string>(rtn),
                     str.cbegin(),
                     str.cend(),
                     rgx_pattern,
                     "");
  return rtn;
}
```

This function takes in input a string and "fixes the spaces problem".

[Here a demo](https://ideone.com/wC2Na4)

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer using `regex` as I would like to become more familiar with it. I understand some parts of the pattern but not all of them. Is there a reference you would recommend? I try to piece together expressions from other questions most times unsuccessfully.

Comment: @user5468794 I can suggest to see some videos on youtube about *regular expressions*. Note in my code there is a trick: in C/C++ in order to produce a back-slash you need to escape it with another back-slash. So the real regex in my example should be: `"\s+(?=[\.,])"`

Answer (score 1):

On a loop search for string " ," and if you find one replace that to ",":

```
std::string str = "...";
while( true ) {
    auto pos = str.find( " ," );
    if( pos == std::string::npos )
         break;
    str.replace( pos, 2, "," );
}
```

Do the same for " .". If you need to process different space symbols like tab use regex and proper group.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to use regex for C++, also not sure if C++ supports PCRE regex, anyway I post this answer for the regex (I could delete it if it doesn't work for C++).

You can use this regex:

```
\s+(?=[,.])
```

**[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nlIMSk/1)**

Comment: If you look at the answer you were correct. It does work for c++, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no need to use a vector of char: you could very well do the same by using an std::string.

Then, your approach can't work because your copy is independent of the position of the space. Unfortunately you have to remove only spaces around the punctuation,  and not those between words.

Modifying your code slightly you could delay copy of spaces waiting to the value of the first non-space: if it's not a punctuation you'd copy a space before the character, otherwise you just copy the non-space char (thus getting rid of spaces.

Similarly, once you've copied a punctuation just loop and ignore the following spaces until the first non-space char.

I could have written code. It would have been shorter. But i prefer letting you finish your homework with full understanding of the approach.